# Route using user_id Angular +2

Tags: angular

I have this routing config:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: MainComponent,
        canActivate: [SiteRouteGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: 'home',
                component: HomepageComponent,
                canActivate: [SiteRouteGuard]
            },
            {
                path: 'profile',
                component: ProfileComponent,
                canActivate: [SiteRouteGuard]
            },
            {
                path: '**',
                redirectTo: '/home',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }

];
```

When I navigate to profile the url become `http://localhost:4200/profile` and everything is alright, But how can I achieve the same url using my user_id for every user registered in the site. How can I make my url becom `http://localhost:4200/my_name`

Answer (score 0):

If you check this page from the Angular docs
[Here detail](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5#delete-hero-details-from-heroescomponent)

Based on that, this shall work:

```
{path: 'profile/:id', component: ProfileComponent}
```

You should also change in your template, for example:

```
<a *ngFor="let user of users" routerLink="/profile/{{user.id}}">
```

Please read the doc carefully.

Comment: After applying this I got `http://localhost:4200/profile/my_name` and not `http://localhost:4200/my_name`

Comment: what u can do is just remove profile in both code snippets. Then it shall work.